# Why does EasyPlot make commands invisible in GHCi?

Tags: haskell

Minimal working example:

1. Start GHCi
2. `import` [`Graphics.EasyPlot`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/easyplot-1.0/docs/Graphics-EasyPlot.html)
3. `plot X11 sin`

On my system, as expected, a plot of the sine function appears in a window, GHCi displays `True` (the value of the `IO Bool` that `plot` returned, indicating a successful plot) and a fresh command prompt appears.

Unexpectedly, when I type, no text appears at the command prompt until I hit enter. Then the text I typed becomes visible, and GHCi reacts as expected to whatever command I entered. When I type at the next command prompt, the same thing happens. So far, I've found two ways to get GHCi back to normal:

- Running `:l` to load a file.
- Quitting and restart.

Why does this happen, and how can I prevent it?

---

Things that don't prevent the behavior:

- Calling `plot` from the `main` function in a file and running it using the `:main` command in GHCi.
- Plotting to a file, using the `PNG` terminal, instead of to a window.
- Using `plot'` instead of `plot`.

Things that don't get GHCi back to normal:

- Running `:m` to unload all modules.

Answer (score 4):

I can reproduce what you describe (ghc-7.8.4, fedora 21, x86_64, xmonad).

It is not a ghci feature, you get the same behaviour in a shell.

```
gnuplot -e "set terminal x11 persist ; plot sin(x)"
```

(This is (roughly) the command that is sent to the shell by EasyPlot,
cf. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/easyplot-1.0/docs/src/Graphics-EasyPlot.html#exec )

Plot window appears, shell prompt appears, but shell does not (seem to) work.

You can just move the mouse pointer to the plot window, then back to the shell - this seems to make it work.

Comment: Interesting! I don't get the same behavior in a shell, and moving the mouse / focus back and forth between the plot window and GHCi doesn't work for me. It's sounding like this must be some weird interaction between gnuplot, GHCi, the windowing system, and the terminal...

Comment: I am not surprised that different windowing systems behave differently, but I am surprised that typing a command in a shell behaves differently from sending the command programmatically (via `rawSystem`). You could find out the exact command that is being sent (e.g., put a fake `gnuplot` executable in your PATH that actually contains `echo $*`) and execute what you see in a shell, and compare.  (For me, `set term x11 persist; plot "plot1.dat" with lines`.)